# Non-intrusive configuration buttons

Tags: interface-design, critique, iphone, button

In my iPhone app's home page I need to display the groups a user is part of, as well as have buttons to make and join a group. I've added buttons that lead to the pages where group creation/joining is handled. Here's a picture:

[image: pic]

These buttons are important especially when the user first installs the app and isn't part of any groups yet. However, they're pretty intrusive and look out of place to me. As a computer science student who's not really good with UI I was wondering if anybody could please give me any tips to make the buttons fit in better on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one opinion:

[image]

Information: I'm sure that something must be visible

The buttons: The size of the texts need some investigation. These can be unnecessary big. I wrote setting1 and Setting2. I believe that one general word should be enough - especially if there is a proper help or some hinting text.

*Addendum due the comment:* In your comment you had much better buttons. their only problem = too thin, if there's nothing else at the bottom part. Check this:

[image]

Alternatively try thicker button strokes and text.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have any information I want to display. However, I agree text in the buttons and the buttons themselves are probably too big. Do you think this is better?  http://imgur.com/a/Wxwz9